# How to configure Elasticsearch in Strapi?

Tags: elasticsearch, strapi

I'm trying to integrate Elasticsearch into my Strapi project for efficient search functionality. I have Elasticsearch installed and running on my system, but I'm unsure about the necessary steps to configure it properly within Strapi. Could someone provide guidance on how to configure Elasticsearch in Strapi and ensure it works seamlessly for searching and indexing data? Any help or example configurations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have attempted to implement the instructions provided in the article "How to Set Up and Use Elasticsearch with Strapi" available at https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-set-up-and-use-elasticsearch-with-strapi. However, despite following the steps outlined in the article, I was unable to successfully configure Elasticsearch in my Strapi project.

Comment: Can you explain what you did from the article and where you stand? Any errors you can share?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.